# ReflectionMethod of ArrayObject constructor - getNumberOfRequiredParameters bug?

Tags: php, reflection, arrayobject

We can create a new instances of ArrayObject passing an array as constructor parameter

```
$arrayObject = new ArrayObject([1,2,3]);
```

but that is also fine:

```
$arrayObject = new ArrayObject();
```

However

```
$arrayObjectReflection = new ReflectionClass('ArrayObject');
$arrayObjectReflection->getConstructor()->getNumberOfRequiredParameters();
```

Returns **1**.

Am I misunderstand optional parameters in PHP or that is just a bug?

P.S: I'm using PHP 5.5.9 (Zend Engine)